# Terminal Glyphs are not showing

Tags: terminal, windows-terminal, oh-my-posh

this has been a problem for a while now, my windows terminal is not showing any glyphs or icons, instead a unicode box shows or even nothing... what do i do to fix it?

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJQLH.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpoN1.png)

i thought it would be the font but it is set to `Cascadia Code nerd font` in the profile settings,  my laptop is based on arabic and i had to change the language to use it, sometimes instead of glyphs it shows arabic texts.

Answer (score -1):

The challenge with Nerd Fonts is the name sometimes isn't what you think it is. If you have this font installed (make sure it's system wide), validate the font name in the Windows Font viewer and adjust accordingly.